# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar todo en laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel

```
$array = array_pluck($conversacion,'id');
          foreach ($array as $a) {
            $message = DB::table('messages')
            ->join('users', 'users.id','messages.id_emisor')
            ->where('messages.conversation_id', $a)->get();


            echo $message;
          }
```

El echo me imprime lo siguiente y esta bien:

```
[{"id":2,
"mensaje":"mensaje 3,
"name":"Gotze",
},

 {"id":3,
 "mensaje":"mensaje 4,
 "name":"Mario",
 }]

 [{"id":3,
 "mensaje":"mensaje 5",
 "name":"Mario",
 }]
```

El problema es que si mando la variable a la vista de blade solo me devuelve dos de los objetos.

para probar asi lo hago en la vista:

```
@foreach($message as $m)
    Envio: {{$m->name}} <br>
    Mensaje: {{$m->mensaje}} <br>
@endforeach
```

estoy tratando de mostrar todas la conversaciones como el messenger de facebook

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y muestra el código que utilizas en blade para imprimirlos.

Comment: y porque no envias la variable a la vista y en ella si haces el foreach ?

Comment: si ya lo hice, el caso es que trato de obtener todas los mensajes que tiene el usuario logueado, pero en blade no lo muestra.

Comment: ¿cuáles son los dos objetos que muestra en la vista?

Comment: @Shaz  bueno la cuestion es que ya en blade no me muestra todo los mensajes, como cuando lo imprimo con el echo en el controlador. Lo siento si no me entienden no soy bueno explicando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la query deberia ser:

```
    //array con los id a buscar. en tu caso estas usando $array
    $a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    //query obtiene todos los mensajes a la vez sin usar foreach
    // y en una sola variable
    $message = DB::table('messages')
        ->join('users', 'users.id','messages.id_emisor')
        ->whereIn('messages.conversation_id', $a)->get();

    //enviar la variable $message a la vista
```

la clausula whereIn te permite comparar con un array en vez de tener que iterar y hacer una consulta por item del array.

Comment: gracias suena bien tu respuesta voy a probar a ver que tal me va

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta me servio, ya estoy un paso mas cerca de crear mi pequeño menssenger, espero no tener mas problemas jajaja

Comment: De nada. Sigue con tu proyecto

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que hacer esto

```
return view('tuplantilla', $array);
```

Y en tu tupalntilla.blade.php

```
@foreach($array as $valor)
{{ $valor->mensaje }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: sii lo se, el problema es que no estoy obteniendo toda la informacion que deberia